# How to check if NSTextfield is already truncating the text (... at the end)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, truncate, nstextfield

I've searched around on how to perform this but I can't find any answer.
I'd like to know if my `NSTextfield` is already truncating the text (... at the end) without having to check the length of its `stringValue`. I need to do this to know if I should set a tooltip on my `NSTextfield` (acting like a simple label).

The reason I don't want to check the length of my textfield's `stringValue` it's because there are some characters that occupy more space than others, so that's not very accurate
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet might be to use an `NSTextView` instead of a `NSTextField`. If you use an `NSTextView` you can get the `NSTextContainer` of the `NSTextView` using the `textContainer` property. The container can tell you the `containerSize` (the space the text is drawn in).

`NSString` objects respond to the method `sizeWithAttributes:`. You can use the resulting `NSSize` struct to grab the width of the text if drawn with the given attributes. See the "Constants" section of the [NSAttributedString Application Kit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) to figure out what attributes are relevant.

If the `containerSize` width is less than the `sizeWithAttributes:` width then the text will be truncated.

**EDIT:** Apologies, this is only true with no `lineFragmentPadding`, but the default `lineFragmentPadding` is non-zero. Either subtract the `textContainer.lineFragmentPadding` from `containerSize.width` or use the `NSTextContainer` `setLineFragmentPadding:` method to set it to `0`.

I suppose you could also make some assumptions about the text area relative to the size of the `NSTextField` and use the `sizeWithAttributes:` `NSString` method in conjunction with that, but that is not as clean.

**EDIT 2:** I realized I did not address the OP's interest in truncating the text using ellipses. The example code below uses truncation in the `NSTextView`. I also thought I might as well throw in some code that makes the `NSTextView` a little more similar in appearance to the `NSTextField` by putting it inside of a `NSBox`. Adding a check for size to determine if a tooltip should be displayed would be a simple addition to the code below using the information already mentioned above.

```
NSString* string = @"Hello World.";

// get the size the text will take up using the default font
NSSize textBounds = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{}];

// Create a border view that looks more or less like the border used around
// text fields
NSBox* borderView = [[NSBox alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 60, textBounds.height+4)];
[borderView setBoxType:NSBoxCustom];
[borderView setBorderType:NSBezelBorder];
[borderView setContentViewMargins:NSMakeSize(0, 0)];
[borderView setFillColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];

// Create the text view
NSTextView* textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 60, textBounds.height)];
[textView setTextContainerInset:NSMakeSize(2, 0)];
[textView.textContainer setLineFragmentPadding:0];
[textView setEditable:YES];

// Set the default paragraph style so the text is truncated rather than
// wrapped
NSMutableParagraphStyle* parStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[parStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

// Do not let text get squashed to fit
[parStyle setTighteningFactorForTruncation:0.0];

[textView setDefaultParagraphStyle:parStyle];
[parStyle release];

// Set text
[textView setString:string];

// add NSTextView to border view
[borderView addSubview:textView];
[textView release];

// add NSBox to view you want text view displayed in
[self addSubview:borderView];
[borderView release];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the NSTextField will slightly shrink the text if it's close to fitting without truncating. [Both of these text fields have the same size font.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wrJtj.png)

Comment: @JohnSauer Good point. This actually occurs for NSTextViews as well. It is the default behavior of the truncating algorithm to attempt to move characters closer together before truncating. In my second edit I stop this from happening by using the `setTighteningFactorForTruncation:` method of the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` class.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll try it asap and i'll let you know

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but I think that this answer does not answer the initial question... Right ?

Comment: @Regis_AG OP wanted to do something that I am pretty sure cannot be done. There is no method to determine if an `NSTextfield` is truncating its text. So, I provided the best solution I could for displaying editable text, truncating overflow, and determining if overflow will occur.

Answer (score 18):

For future visitors, you can use the `-[NSCell expansionFrameWithFrame:inView:]` method to determine if truncation is taking place.  From the header:

> Allows the cell to return an expansion cell frame if cellFrame is
>   too small for the entire contents in the view.  ...<snip>... If the frame is not too
>   small, return an empty rect, and no expansion tool tip view will be
>   shown. By default, NSCell returns NSZeroRect, while some subclasses
>   (such as NSTextFieldCell) will return the proper frame when required.

In short, you can tell if an `NSTextField` is truncating like this:

```
    NSRect expansionRect = [[self cell] expansionFrameWithFrame: self.frame inView: self];
    BOOL truncating = !NSEqualRects(NSZeroRect, expansionRect);
```

Comment: this is the best solution

Comment: Could you please provide an Swift 3 solution? I was not able to adapt the Obj-C code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by looking at the frame of the text field's field editor. You check its width in controlTextDidBeginEditing, and then again in controlTextDidEndEditing. If the latter value is larger, then the text has been truncated. The following is implemented in the text field's delegate (I created an ivar for initialWidth):

```
- (void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if (! initialWidth) 
        initialWidth = ((NSTextView *)aNotification.userInfo[@"NSFieldEditor"]).frame.size.width;
}


- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if (initialWidth) { //Make sure that beginEditing is called first
        NSInteger finalWidth = ((NSTextView *)aNotification.userInfo[@"NSFieldEditor"]).frame.size.width;
        if (finalWidth - initialWidth > 1) NSLog(@"We have truncation");
        NSLog(@"Final: %ld  Initial: %ld", finalWidth,initialWidth);
    }
}
```

This seems to work most of the time, including if you type in a long string, then delete until it fits again. In a few cases, it gave me the log message when I was one character past the end of the text field, but I did not get the ellipsis when editing ended.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4 solution using ipmcc as base

It will resize one by one until it fit or fontsize = 3

```
var size_not_ok = true

var conter = 0
let mininum_font_size = 3 // will resize ultil 3 
while size_not_ok || conter < 15 { // will try 15 times maximun
    let expansionRect = le_nstextfield.expansionFrame(withFrame: le_nstextfield.frame)

    let truncated = !NSEqualRects(NSRect.zero, expansionRect)

    if truncated {

        if let actual_font_size : CGFloat = le_nstextfield.font?.fontDescriptor.object(forKey: NSFontDescriptor.AttributeName.size) as? CGFloat {

            le_nstextfield.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: actual_font_size - 1)

            if actual_font_size < mininum_font_size {
                break
            } 
        }
    } else {        
        size_not_ok = false
    }
    conter  = conter + 1
}
```