# NSTextField: How to detect when a string is too long?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield

In my UI I have an NSTextField (used as a label). This text field's string value changes dynamically. I'd like to know when its string value is too long to display. I've configured the text field to truncate its contents:

`myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail`

which works fine but I need to know **when** truncation occurs because in that situation I need to do something else in my UI.

Comment: similar question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430193/how-to-check-if-nstextfield-is-already-truncating-the-text-at-the-end)

Comment: Create an attributed string and check its length.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calculate number of character the label can take ([determine the maximum number of characters a UILabel can take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193520/determine-the-maximum-number-of-characters-a-uilabel-can-take)). 
Suppose, the label takes x characters then check, if(x < label.text.characters.count) { //Do you work.}

Comment: How do you use UILabel in Cocoa?